# Java/Android - How to set timeout external service call with handler

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback, timeout

My scenario is an onCreate() activity method which executes the following code (simplified):

```
dialog.show(); //loading wheel
try {
    remote.sendRequest(myData, new MyHandler());
}
catch (Exception e) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    //log and react    
}

class MyHandler extends SDKSpecificCompiledHandler {

    @Override
    public void failure() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        //do stuff
    }

    @override
    public void success() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        //do stuff
    }

}

//I have read-only access to this handler!
public abstract class SDKSpecificCompiledHandler {
    public abstract void success(JSONObject successData);
    public abstract void failure(JSONObject errorData);
}
```

Explanation: A remote service is called passing an handler that gets called when he's done. A loading wheel (dialog) is shown to the user until a success, failure or exception happens.

The problem is when the service gets successfully called but no response ever comes. In that case `dialog.dismiss()` doesn't get called and the loading wheel keeps spinning for ever.

What I need is a sort of timeout which dismisses the dialog (and possibly takes other actions) after some seconds if the server doesn't get back.

My first though would be to create a new thread for the service call, and right after the launch set a timer which dismisses the dialog.
Would it be a good idea?

Thank you,

**EDIT**:

The service is third-party/not editable. I'm using a pre-compiled artifact.

Comment: why not use an existing http library, tested and verified by many apps - okhttp, retrofit, volley? that would handle all sorts of http issues for you, including timeout. and anyway, creating a new thread is not a good idea. Your network call should be on a worker thread anyway, so just attach a handler to that thread and post a delayed message to handle your timeout case. if your call returns before the delayed message, clear the handler from all messages, or something like that

Comment: Thanks for you answer Vkislincins. As by edit I can't use any http library for the request because I'm actually calling from a third-party SDK. I might use the approach that you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: ok maybe post more about the SDK that you're using and what's that `remote` object

Comment: It's a private SDK, I can't. `remote` relies on another service. As a consequence `remote` itself is reachable **but**, he might not get back to the handler since it supports only _success_ and _failure_. That's why I need my own logic to implement a timeout. Something that shuts the dialog down and informs the user that the server does not get back.

Comment: I'm confused. `remote` is part of the mysterious private SDK, but it happily accepts your custom class as a parameter? this doesn't make any sense. Also why are you overriding methods in Handler class if it's a custom class and not extending any other object?

Comment: That code is simplified. Of course my handler extends a specific handler, which requires to override just success() and failure().

Comment: yes but posting such 'simplified' code really limits how we can help you, doesn't it? Cause I really don't know what Handler you're talking about. Is it `android.os.Handler` or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

Still not really sure what you're trying to achieve but if you want to run some code after some time on main thread (i.e. your code will do stuff to the UI), you can use a `android.os.Handler`

```
    mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do stuff on UI thread
        }
    },10000);
```

When your call returned from the server, simply cancel the messages on the queue:

```
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use time out in service call itself, You can set the time out with service , If you need know how to set the time out then I should know what kind of service you are using ?

One more thing is that if you are using a loader you should make that loader in such a way that it can be cancel by the client.

Comment: Hi Joyal, thanks for your reply. The service that I'm using is a third party  service which is not editable. I'm importing an artifact to use it.

Comment: that might have the option to set a time out, please check it. If it does not have then you should cancel it using a timer.